# Windows / MySQL 5.5. / Crash on startup on exeption 0xc0000005

Tags: mysql, crash

i have Windows 2016 Standard OS with installed MySQL 5.5.33.0.
This morning I found out that the mysql server is not running and cannot be turned on. When i try to turn it on, it crashes immediately, and there is only exception information 0xc0000005 in Event Viewer. I can't even run mysqlcheck because it doesn't work when mysqld isn't running.

I will be very grateful for any advice.

I was able to enable logging and set paths in MySQL settings. There are quite a few entries in the log with this text (numbers change):

```
210107 10:28:21 InnoDB: Error: page 33382 log sequence number 114951961648 
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 111386529682. 
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB 
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. 
See InnoDB: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html 
InnoDB: for more information.
```

```
210107 10:32:33  InnoDB: Error: Insert buffer insert fails; page free 43, dtuple size 50 
                 InnoDB: Cannot insert index record DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;  
                    0: len 40; hex 436f6d70757465722050726573732020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020; 
                asc Computer Press                          ;;  
                    1: len 4; hex 800070da; asc   p ;;  
                InnoDB: The table where this index record belongs 
                InnoDB: is now probably corrupt. Please run CHECK TABLE on 
                InnoDB: that table. 
                InnoDB: space 0, page 109621, zip_size 0, bitmap bits 1
```

Progress update:
I managed to start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery = 3 and it even runs for a while. If I run mysqlcheck.exe --all-databases --auto-repair, it reports corrupt in some tables of this type:

```
Warning: InnoDB: Index 'ix_linear_pole' contains 1683314 entries, should be 1683294.
```

However, the check does not run to the end and for one specific table the whole mysql server crashes again.

UPDATE: I found out that the error is in the loaded command in the InnoDB buffer, but I don't know how to delete it. Each time I turn on the server, a command in the buffer crash it.

Comment: Did you check mysql's own log

Comment: I can't find any log in the mysql folder, I also looked in ProgramData but there are two logs and both are unreadable (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1).

Comment: Can you see the `my.ini` or `my.cnf` files? If you can edit them to find a param called `log-error`

Comment: I was able to enable logging and set paths in MySQL settings. There are quite a few entries in the log with this text (numbers change):

210107 10:28:21  InnoDB: Error: page 33382 log sequence number 114951961648
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 111386529682.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.

Comment: So I'm trying the procedure from the web.

Comment: `210107 10:32:33  InnoDB: Error: Insert buffer insert fails; page free 43, dtuple size 50
InnoDB: Cannot insert index record DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 40; hex 436f6d70757465722050726573732020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020; asc Computer Press                          ;;
 1: len 4; hex 800070da; asc   p ;;

InnoDB: The table where this index record belongs
InnoDB: is now probably corrupt. Please run CHECK TABLE on
InnoDB: that table.
InnoDB: space 0, page 109621, zip_size 0, bitmap bits 1`

Comment: ADD THOSE TO THE QUESTION (using edit link) Nobody reads code in a  comment

Comment: Did you change the system time on the computer runnning MySQL?

Comment: I dont know, server is VM on different place. Im external admin for application running on that server (and using mysql).

Comment: Im admin of library software, im not database administrator. Unfortunately, I also installed MySQL as part of the deployment, so I have to deal with the crash. This is the first time my MySQL server has stopped like this and is not running.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of research, I found that MySQL was failing to load InnoDB Buffer. The easiest way was to add a command to my.ini

```
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

However, the database is started only for SHOW data. Using mysqldump, I backed up the data without indexes. Then I deleted the database from the server, I also deleted the logs and database data from the system (C: \ ProgramData \ ... \ MySQL \ data \ ibdata and iblog0 and iblog1). Then I stopped MySQL and removed innodb_force_recovery. The database then ran in but without data.
I uploaded the original data back using normal recovery and created indexes.

From that moment on, everything works without problems.